# PI operator with two variables

Tags: products

$$\prod_{\begin{array}{c}b=1,\cdots,B \\ d=1,\cdots,D\end{array}}e^{-\lambda(b,d)}\,\frac{\lambda(b,d)^{n(b,d)}}{n(b,d)!}. $$

In the above expression, what does the PI operator stand for with two variables?

Can I think that is dual PI operators such as

$$ \prod_{d=0}^{D}\prod_{b=0}^{B} $$

Thank you for considering my request.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Just as a note (since this took me some time to parse), I think that you are using the word "dual" here to mean "a pair of Pi operators", i.e. iterated products.  You might want to consider using a different word here, as the word "dual" has special meaning in mathematics (e.g. an operator may have a dual operator that acts on some related space in a complementary manner).  The sentence "Can I think of this as a pair of Pi operators...?" might be more clear.

Comment: I appreciate for your constructive comment.